# Exclaiming Questions

Tags: punctuation, questions, question-mark, exclamations, exclamation-mark

What is the correct way to write a question you would verbally ask in a higher tone of voice?

> How is this possible?!

OR

> How is this possible!?

The subtlety lies in the punctuation.

Thanks

Comment: There is no consensus. See http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/531/is-there-a-standard-ordering-for-the-question-mark-and-the-exclamation-mark-used http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/114461/punctuating-a-question-ending-with-an-exclamatory-quotation-in-american-style and http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/41991/punctuation-of-an-exclamative-question .

Comment: @choster: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Alas, there IS a punctuation mark for such a thing, but the interrobang sadly goes unused due to it not appearing on a standard QWERTY keyboard.  How could they leave out such a perfect punctuation mark‽

Comment: @ Yasky: I've closevoted as Off Topic, because any relevant reference will tell you that grammatically you're required to use a question mark after a question. Any in any real-world written context it should be fairly obvious whether there's any element of surprise/exclamation in any given "question". If you're writing the words yourself, consider devices such as ["How is it possible?" **exclaimed** {John}](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22how+is+it+possible+exclaimed%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Comment: @Zibbobz The interrobang goes happily unused due to it being a horrible bastardisation that at best falls into the "it was funnier the first time" category.